# Comparing a date and time in one sheet to shift calendar to get the shift

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, date, time

I am having trouble.

Example data on worksheet1

[image]

On another worksheet2 I have a list of date/times

[image]

I have a loop that's built to set between the timestamps but inside that I need to compare the timestamp to the calendar and fill in the shift column on Worksheet2. Any suggestion .. need to be a macro because my list of timestamps moves and index/match formula will not work because it will crush my CPU (many many lines).

Basically, this will be a tool for filling out shift for any data I pull with time stamps.

```vb
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    On Local Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a range", Type:=8)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Workbooks(rng.Parent.Parent.Name).Activate
    Sheets(rng.Parent.CodeName).Activate
    rng.Select
    mystartrange = rng
    
    NewCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Cells(1, NewCol).Value = "SHIFT"
    
    numberofCells = Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    
    For Eachdate = 2 To numberofCells
        comparedate = rng.Cells(Eachdate, 1).Value
        'compare code and fill in corrisponing shift"
    Next
    End Sub
```

Retrieve shift by comparing a table of dates (calendar) to a time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

### Lookup Data (VBA)

[image]

```vb
Sub PopulateShifts()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the source values to the source array ('sData').
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = 3 ' Start Time, End Time, Shift
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount, scCount).Offset(1) ' first 3 columns
    End With
    
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Shift the data rows containing valid date pairs to the top.
    
    Dim sValue As Variant, sr As Long, sn As Long, sc As Long
    Dim IsInvalidDateFound As Boolean
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If Not IsDate(sData(sr, 1)) Or Not IsDate(sData(sr, 2)) Then
            If IsInvalidDateFound Then
                sn = sn + 1
                For sc = 1 To scCount
                    sData(sn, sc) = sData(sr, sc)
                Next sc
            Else
                IsInvalidDateFound = True
                sn = sr - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
            
    If sn > 0 Then srCount = sn
    
    ' Write the header and values from the destination lookup range
    ' to the destination array ('dData').
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = 2 ' Stamp, Shift
    
    Dim drg As Range, drCount As Long
    
    With dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        drCount = .Rows.Count
        Set drg = .Resize(drCount, dcCount) ' first 2 columns
    End With
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: dData = drg.Columns(1).Value
    
    ' In the destination array ('dData'), using the required logic,
    ' replace the destination header and lookup values with the results.
    
    dData(1, 1) = "Shift" ' header
    
    Dim dValue As Variant, dr As Long, IsDateIntervalFound As Boolean
    
    For dr = 2 To drCount
        dValue = dData(dr, 1) ' lookup time
        If IsDate(dValue) Then
            For sr = 1 To srCount
                If dValue < sData(sr, 2) Then ' end
                    If dValue >= sData(sr, 1) Then ' start
                        IsDateIntervalFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next sr
        End If
        If IsDateIntervalFound Then
            IsDateIntervalFound = False
            dData(dr, 1) = sData(sr, 3)
        Else ' not a date or date interval not found
            dData(dr, 1) = Empty
        End If
    Next dr
    
    ' Write the header and the values from the destination array
    ' to the destination result range.
                                
    drg.Columns(2).Value = dData
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Shifts populated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue lies with your data rather than the code. Let's examine the first Staamp "10/7/2023 8:23." from worksheet2. If this marks the start of a work shift, someone seems to have arrived late. However, can you specify which shift this pertains to? It could be either D1 or D2, making it impossible to determine precisely if it's D1 or D2.

Alternatively, this could someone worked overtime, potentially falling under N1 or N2 shifts. Similarly, we can't definitively say whether it's N1 or N2 due to the same ambiguity in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively , if the shift pattern is regular then determine using logic.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FillShift()
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            .Cells(r, 2) = GetShift(.Cells(r, 1))
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows filled", vbInformation
End Sub

Function GetShift(dt As Date) As String
    Dim t As Double, s As String, n As String, wd As String
     
    ' mon tue etc
    wd = WeekdayName(Weekday(dt, vbMonday), True)
    t = dt - Int(dt) ' time only
    
    ' Day
    If t >= TimeSerial(6, 0, 0) And t < TimeSerial(18, 0, 0) Then
         s = "D"
         Select Case wd
            Case "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"
                n = 1
            Case Else
                n = 2
        End Select
    ' Night
    Else
        s = "N"
        n = 1
        Select Case wd
            Case "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"
                n = "1"
                If wd = "Wed" And t >= TimeSerial(18, 0, 0) Then
                    n = "2"
                End If
            Case Else
                n = "2"
                If wd = "Sun" And t >= TimeSerial(18, 0, 0) Then
                    n = "1"
               End If
        End Select
    End If
    GetShift = s & n
End Function
```